# How to avoid planner jumping between 2 possible path

Tags: ros, ros2, navfn, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, recently I'm using Navigation2 release 1.1.0 with Galactic built from source in Ubuntu18.04.

I'm using Smac 2D Planner and TEB controller in my navigation stack, they are run in 10Hz. The localization is provided by another node, all running in a real robot.

To describe my question, here is the video.

[Youtube](https://youtube.com/shorts/eUGsxc30ako)

You can see there are 2 symmetric pathes generated by global planner (both Navfn and Smac 2D). It will cause the robot stuck at the intersection. How can I be sure that it will keep the path as long as there are no blocked space.

If there is any missing information please let me know. Really want some help on it. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402327/how-to-avoid-planner-jumping-between-2-possible-path./) by [stu00608](https://answers.ros.org/users/93347/stu00608/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replan at a reduced rate or check out one of the other provided behavior trees Nav2 provides (or create your own!).

But the specific problem of path oscillation was the motivation behind this particular behavior tree: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bt_navigator/behavior_trees/nav_to_pose_with_consistent_replanning_and_if_path_becomes_invalid.xml which includes both time-based replanning at a reduced rate and event-based replanning due to critical collisions.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stu00608](https://answers.ros.org/users/93347/stu00608/) on 2022-06-15**:
Actually I didn't modify any behavior tree node in nav2 for this task! I'll give it a try, thank you for your reply!

**Comment by [stu00608](https://answers.ros.org/users/93347/stu00608/) on 2022-07-05**:
Hi Steve, I've tried some features in behavior tree, that solves my problem! But I realized that I wrote a wrong version of release that I'm using, it's 1.0.12 . There are less bt nodes than humble. Is there any plan to backport those functionalities back to galactic?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-07-06**:
Some are able to be, but not all. Additionally, Galactic is EOL in 4 months, so its nearly out of support anyhow.

**Comment by [stu00608](https://answers.ros.org/users/93347/stu00608/) on 2022-07-07**:
Then I think I should consider to upgrade the distro, thanks for your response!